# How to get category name using WP Query in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am having product with name, description and custom fields. Product also has category name, for example: Carbohydrates.

How can i get the category name using the WP Query class ?

Here's my code:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
 'post_type' => 'food-item',
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'meta_query' => array(
    array(
     'key' => 'include_in_dont_like_foods',
     'value' => 'Yes',
     'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
  )
));
       
while ($query->have_posts()) {
  $query->the_post();

   $food = array(
     'id' => get_the_id(),
     'title' => get_the_title(),
     'category_name' => ???
   );

   print_r($food);
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: You'll have to use [wp_get_post_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the result using the get_the_terms() function. Pass the current id using get_the_id() and taxonomy in get_the_terms()

Then call the name property like $categoryName[0]->name as shown below:

```
while ($query->have_posts()) {
  $query->the_post();

  $categoryName = get_the_terms(get_the_id(), 'food-category');

  $food = array(
    'id' => get_the_id(),
    'title' => get_the_title(),
    'category_name' => $categoryName[0]->name
  );

  print_r($food);
}
```